# Why does my WebPage Change When I put it on IIS

Tags: asp.net, html, css, iis

I write asp.net applications for a living.  I look at the page through debug (localhost) and everything looks fine, but often once I put the files on IIS and view the page: things are different.  Some controls are shifted, and widths are changed. EXACT same css and html.

Is this an asp Server issue or IIS or what?

Comment: Have you looked at the page in release mode on your localhost?

Comment: @mikerobi No just debug... I'll try that though.  Does release mode change things related to css/html though?

Comment: Is it possible that you have some ISAPI modules or anything on the IIS server that might be tweaking the HTML a bit?

Comment: Are you using the same browser, or the one on the target server? Quirks mode comes to mind.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Yeah, using IE 8 in both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" under your "Compatibility View Settings"